# Using generics for a better way to solve this

Tags: java, generics

I'm pretty sure I can solve this problem with Java generics so I wanted to ask...Let's say I have a few classes that each implement a common interface, there's a method in the common interface called `getData`, which I'd like to make generic. The problem I have is that each class returns a different object type, so ideally I'd like these to be generic, then in the implementation class that calls `getData`, convert them back to their original types. If I were to cast to an `Object` and back to specific types I can see how that would work, but can I accomplish the same end result with Generics?

Here is some pseudo code to outline the problem:

```
public ClassA implements interface x {

    private CustomObjectA customObjectA;
    private Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectA>> dataMap;

...

    public Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectA>> getData() {
        return this.dataMap;
    }
}

public ClassB implements interface x {

    private CustomObjectA customObjectB;
    private Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectB>> dataMap;

...

    public Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectB>> getData() {
        return this.dataMap;
    }
}

public interface x {
    public Map<DateTime, Map<String, genericObject>> getData();
}


public ClassC {
    public testGeneric(x objX) {

        CustomObjectA cOA = objX.getData();
        CustomObjectB cOB = objX.getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: are CustomObjectB and CustomObjectA completely unrelated?

Comment: Yes, they have completely different members

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably want is a generic interface :

```
public interface X<T> {
    Map<DateTime, Map<String, T>> getData();
}

public class A implements X<CustomObjectA> {
    @Override
    public Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectA>> getData() {
        ...
    }
}

public class B implements X<CustomObjectB> {
    @Override
    public Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectB>> getData() {
        ...
    }
}

public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X<CustomObjectA> a = new A();
        Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectA>> m1 = a.getData();
        X<CustomObjectB> b = new B();
        Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectB>> m2 = b.getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect example, thank you, that cleared things up immediately

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
public interface X<T> {
    Map<Date, Map<String, T>> getData();
}

public class ClassA implements X<CustomObjectA> {

    private CustomObjectA customObjectA;
    private Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectA>> dataMap;

...

    public Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectA>> getData() {
        return this.dataMap;
    }
}

public class ClassB implements X<CustomObjectB> {

    private CustomObjectB customObjectB;
    private Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectB>> dataMap;

...

    public Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectB>> getData() {
        return this.dataMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Map;


public class GenericsExample {

  public static interface X<T> {
    public Map<Calendar, Map<String, T>> getData();
  }

  public static class A implements X<Long> {
    private Map<Calendar, Map<String, Long>> dataMap;
    public Map<Calendar, Map<String, Long>> getData() {
        return this.dataMap;
    }
  }

  public static class B implements X<Double> {
      private Map<Calendar, Map<String, Double>> dataMap;
      public Map<Calendar, Map<String, Double>> getData() {
          return this.dataMap;
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    X<Long> a = new A();
    X<Double> b = new B();
    Map<Calendar, Map<String, Long>> longData = a.getData();
    Map<Calendar, Map<String, Double>> doubleData = b.getData();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't suffice to just make the interface generic?

```
public interface x <T> {
    public Map<String,T> getData()
}
```

then of course the classes must implement the interface like

```
public class ClassA implements x<CustomObjectA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your CustomObjectA and CustomObjectB extend a common superclass. Then, modify the method declaration in your interface to read:

```
public Map<DateTime, Map<String, ? extends CustomObjectSuperclass>> getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help:

```
public interface GenericObject<T> {
    public Map<DateTime, Map<String, T>> getData();
}

public class ClassA implements GenericObject<CustomObjectA> {
    public Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectA>> getData() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class ClassB implements GenericObject<CustomObjectB> {
    public Map<DateTime, Map<String, CustomObjectB>> getData() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer might seem a bit off since I won't directly answer your question, but it might be the most appropriate one (I can't really tell since you don't give that many details on what your classes do).

If CustomObjectA and CustomObjectB are really completely unrelated, then don't define an interface for the `getData` method.  This method returns something completely different for ClassA and ClassB and it does not make much sense to group them under the same interface.  You can still have ClassA.getData() and ClassB.getData(), but you'll never be able to use inheritance to use both in the same piece of code.  But it should never happen anyway since what is returned by getData is completely different in both cases.

In your question:

> then in the implementation class that calls getData, convert them back
>   to their original types.

does not sound right.  You should rethink your design on a higher level rather than just trying to make some parts generics.